# Why does my parent's context rerender children not using it?

Tags: reactjs

While testing the React contexts and hooks, I stepped upon a strange behavior I can’t explain. In the following code, when ContextHookInfo updates it’s own context (HookContext), thanks to a console.log() I forgot to remove I know that RefForwarder is rerendered, even if it doesn’t share any props with ContextHookInfo. Does it mean that any context change in a parent (TestApp()) forces the rerendering of its children?

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext([null, () => { }]);
const HookContext = React.createContext({ selectedTheme: UseContextTheme.light, themeSetter: () => { } });

function ContextHookInfo(props) {
    const themeContext = React.useContext(HookContext);     // useContext hook testing without the need of a provider
    return (
        <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", margin: "10px" }}>
            <p style={themeContext.selectedTheme.style}>Hook {props.name} theme color is {themeContext.selectedTheme.name}</p>
            <p>{props.comment}</p>
            <button onClick={() => themeContext.themeSetter(themeContext.selectedTheme === UseContextTheme.light ? UseContextTheme.dark : UseContextTheme.light)}>Change hook theme</button>
        </div>
    );
}

function TestApp() {
    const themeHook = React.useState("light");
    const [useContextSelectedTheme, useContextThemeSetter] = useState(UseContextTheme.dark);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <ThemeContext.Provider value={themeHook}>
                ...
                <RefForwarder />
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
            ...
            <HookContext.Provider value={{ selectedTheme: useContextSelectedTheme, themeSetter: useContextThemeSetter }}>
                <ContextHookInfo name="with provider" comment="will take the provider value and will be able to change it" />
            </HookContext.Provider>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: What happens if you rerender `TestApp` for any other reason, independent of context? I bet that `RefForwarder` will be rerendered in this case, too.

Comment: You're right ! Even a parent state change (not a context) rerender the other component! But... why? There is absolutemy no reason :(

Comment: If I understand correctly, `useState` returns a fresh array each time (the elements are stable, but not the array itself). So, `ThemeProvider.Context` sees the change in its props and is forced to rerender. Not sure how to fix this properly, though.

Comment: That is correct, context (and the second test with a state outside context) changes. My question is : why children which do not depend on those data rerender? I think I remember reading somewhere that with a context change, it may/can happen, but with a useState, I really don't see a reason why React would consider rerendering everything :( EDIT: by the way, there are two different contexts, and modifying the second one rerender children of the first one, unchanged. That is in fact my question key.